# $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$, with $A$ and $C$ simple rings, but $B$ is not a simple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be three associative $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a field.

Assume that $A$ and $C$ are simple rings.
(Recall that a ring $R$ is simple, if it has no two-sided ideals other than $0$ and $R$).

> Is it true that $B$ must also be a simple ring? If not, it would be nice to see a counterexample. Does the characteristic of $k$ relevant to the answer?

It would be nice to see a few counterexamples, according to the commutativity or non-commutativity of the rings concerned. (But just one counterexample will also be ok).

Perhaps it is also relevant to know if $C$ is finitely generated as a $B$-module, etc.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What examples did you consider before asking this?

Comment: A good 75% of what I do in this site is to ask precisely that, sigh… Really: if you had considered one or two examples of this situation you would have noticed immediately what the answer to your question is.

Comment: I thought about polynomial rings.

Comment: What specific example did you think about?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have written polynomial rings but was confused. I actually considered the following non-commutative case: $f$ is an endomorphism of the first Weyl algebra $A_1(k,x,y)$, $f:(x,y) \mapsto (p,q)$, so  $A_1(k,p,q)$ is the image of $A_1(k,x,y)$ under $f$. $A:=A_1(k,p,q)$ and $C:=A_1(k,x,y)$. It is known that $A_1$ is simple in characteristic zero, so both $A$ and $C$ are simple.

Comment: And what is $B$?

Comment: Good question. I wished to write that $B$ is an arbitrary ring between $A$ and $C$, but then perhaps it is better to concentrate on $B$ which is obtained from $A$ by 'adjoining' $x$ to $A$, for example.

Comment: And is that $B$ simple?

Comment: This is what I want to know. I do not know what are the properties of such $B$ (adjoining $x$ to $A$).

Comment: Of course, if $x$ is already in $A$, then $B$ is just $A$. (Or perhaps $B$ must equal $C$?).

Comment: BTW, I agree with your second comment "A good..."

Comment: If you wanted to know about that specific example, you could haver asked about that specific example.

Comment: ok, perhaps I will ask about that specific example in a few days (after I will try to think about it myself..)

Answer (score 4):

No, $B$ need not be simple: Let $A=k$, $B=k[X]$, and $C=k(X)$.

Comment: Nice counterexample.Please, what happens if $A$ and $C$ have the same 'dimension'? (Krull dimension/ transcendence degree over $k$/ Gelfand Kirillov dimension). Is it still possible to find a counterexample?

Comment: Nice! This also gives rise to an infinite family of examples by taking $M_{n}(A), M_{n}(B), M_{n}(C)$ for any natural number $n$.

Comment: @user237522: $A$ and $C$ are both fields here, so they have the same Krull dimension.

Comment: I like both answers, and do not know which to accept..

Comment: @carmichael561, yes, thank you for the observation. I guess that there is a counterexample also in the special case of three integral domains, all their fields of fractions are of the same transcendence degree over $k$? (perhaps I should ask this special case in a separate question).

Comment: I think that's worth a separate question.

Comment: Thank you, so I will ask this special case in a new question.

Answer (score 4):

For a finite-dimensional counterexample, let $A=K$ be a field, $C$ a matrix ring over $k$.  Then $A$ and $C$ are simple but there is no reason that $B$ must be.

For a simple example, a nonzero nilpotent matrix generates a subring isomorphic to $k[X]/(X^n)$, which is not simple.

Note that all finite-dimensional counterexamples over a field are non-abelian.